# Sed is not removing the pattern for a list of headers

Tags: linux, sed

Greeting,

I have following headers in a file with multiple dna sequences

```
>10 AC_000167.1
>11 AC_000168.1
>12 AC_000169.1
>MT NC_006853.1
>X AC_000187.1
>GPS_000341582.1 NW_003097887.1
>GPS_000341583.1 NW_003097888.1
>GPS_000341584.1 NW_003097889.1
>GPS_000341585.1 NW_003097890.1
>GPS_000341586.1 NW_003097891.1
```

I am using following sed command to replace everything after the first white space.

```
sed -i 's/[^(>\d+?MT?X?GPS_\d+\.\d+)]\S..\d+\.\d+//g' newHeader.txt
```

The output should like this

```
>10
>11
>12
>MT
>X
>GPS_000341582.1
>GPS_000341583.1
>GPS_000341584.1
>GPS_000341585.1
```

However the command does not seem to work and does not give any error. How can I fix this?

Comment: sed regex are not hte same as pcre-style. eg. `\S`, `+` are not special to sed. Also `[^...]` is a character class that matches items not in `...`

Comment: sed only uses posix regular expressions.  But `'s/ .*//g'` removes anything after the first space.

Comment: you probably need to give examples of lines that should **not** be changed, otherwise all the answers you get are likely to strip every line. For example, is it all lines that start `>`? Or all lines that  start `>` **digits**, `>MT `, `>X `, `>GPS_`, ? etc

Comment: Have you tested my answer? It's the verbatim copy of your expected output. If it's not correct, then your sample input and expected output are wrong

Comment: @GillesQuénot I'd say underspecified rather than "wrong". `sed 's/.[AN].*//'` would also work with the samples but that doesn't make it a correct answer

Comment: _"I am using following sed command to replace everything after the first white space."_ -- this particular goal can be achieved without any complications using `cut -f1 -d' '`.

Comment: @axiac but note "in a file with multiple dna sequences" so possibly some sort of FASTA-type format and the sequence data itself is not to be changed, just the headers

Comment: @jhnc that's why the word _"particular"_ is present in my comment. Unfortunately the question lists only the lines that need this particular processing and it does not show how the lines that do not need it look like.

Comment: @Callie as @jhnc commented above, the file probably contains lines of various formats that need different types of processing (I saw a handful of questions on this subject on SO in the recent past) and the file-wide processing done by `sed` is either not powerful enough for the processing or, if it is, the resulting `sed` program is difficult to understand and maintain. I suggest processing the file with a more powerful language (Python, Ruby, PHP etc.) but since I do not know anything about how the DNA sequences are represented I cannot provide a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -i -E 's/^([^ ]+) .*/\1/' file
```

The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `[^` | ]+ any character except: space (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| ' ' | space |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

With `grep`:

```
grep -oP '^>\S+' file
>10
>11
>12
>MT
>X
>GPS_000341582.1
>GPS_000341583.1
>GPS_000341584.1
>GPS_000341585.1
>GPS_000341586.1
```

The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `>` | > |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

If you want to edit *in place*:

```
 grep -oP '^>\S+' file | sponge file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to strip everything after the first space (**including the space**), but only on some specific lines, then
based on the non-working sed command you provided, this may be what you want:

```
# with a sed that supports -i and -E:
sed -i -E 's/^(>[0-9]+|MT|X|GPS_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[[:space:]].*/\1/' infile
```

By default, many sed metacharacters appear after `\`. The backslash is not needed with `-E`:

- `^` - match start of line
- `(`...`)` - grouping
- `|` - alternation (may not be understood without -E)
- `[`list`]` - any single character from list

  - inside brackets `[:space:]` matches "space" characters (tab, newline, space, etc)
- `{`min`,`max`}` - from min to max repetitions of preceding
- `*` - zero or more of preceding
- `+` - one or more of preceding (not understood without `-E`)

**Warning:** Using `-i` is quite dangerous. Make sure you have backups of the original file in case something goes wrong.

---

Versions of sed that only support POSIX [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) do not support alternation (`\|`).
With these, one can test each alternative separately:

```
# with any POSIX sed:
sed '
    # if line matches, branch to label s
    /^\(>X\)[[:space:]].*/bs
    /^\(>MT\)[[:space:]].*/bs
    /^\(>[0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*/bs
    /^\(>GPS_[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*/bs

    # if we got here nothing matched
    # so just print line and start next cycle
    d

    :s
    # empty regex reuses the previous one
    s//\1/
' infile >tmpfile && mv tmpfile infile
```

Comment: If the bit to be deleted has to match a particular format (eg. `>X ABC` should be unchanged), then the `.*` will need to be replaced with something more specific